# java plugin development about use the eclipse exist editor

Tags: java, plugins, project

I need to develop a plugin which is create my own project and edit it and can run it then output the result in the console, this project include .java file ,how I can use Eclipse own editor more than I develop my own editor?thanks

Comment: Google translate is bad:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The eclipse java editor is part of jdt. You can open a Java Editor like this

```
void showMethod(IMember member) throws PartInitException, JavaModelException {
    ICompilationUnit cu = member.getCompilationUnit();
    IEditorPart javaEditor = JavaUI.openInEditor(cu);
    JavaUI.revealInEditor(javaEditor, (IJavaElement)member);
}
```

You have to make sure that all needed plugins are available. For further information see the [JDT Plug-in Developer Guide](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv/guide/jdt_api_open_editor.htm).